# Parallel computing in R, due to space issues

Tags: r, csv, bigdata, random-forest

I am stuck with huge dataset to be imported in R and then processing it (by randomForest). Basically, I have a csv file of about 100K rows and 6K columns. Importing it directly takes a long time with many warnings regarding space allocations (limit reached for 8061mb). At the end of many warnings, I do get that dataframe in R, but not sure whether to rely on it. Even if I use that dataframe, I am pretty sure running a randomForest on it will definitely be a huge problem. Hence, mine is a two part question:

1. How to efficiently import such a large csv file without any warnings/errors?
2. Once imported into R, how to proceed for using randomForest function on it.

Should we use some package which enhances computing efficiency. Any help is welcome, thanks.

Comment: data.table::fread or readr::read_csv. These read big files a lot faster (fread has the edge). Also specifying the number of rows to be read will help.

Comment: For importing large files, use `data.table::fread`. It's faster than `read.csv`, `ff` and `sqldf::read.csv.sql`.

Comment: Whoa.. Aweseome, the file got imported in 38 seconds with fread.. Thanks phiver & Narendra, for closing out my first issue.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your limit for loading files in R seems to be 8G, try increasing that if your machine have more memory.

If that does not work, one option is that you can submit to MapReduce from R ( see http://www.r-bloggers.com/mapreduce-with-r-on-hadoop-and-amazon-emr/ and https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/sparkr.html). However, Random Forest is not supported in either way yet.